# Forms opening in the background in AX 2009

Tags: axapta, x++

Sometimes when opening a form or when clicking on an object on the form, the form goes inactive or opens in the background. Is there a way to prevent this from occurring programatically?

Comment: Could you give a specific example on when this happens? AX forms do not by it itself go background. They may occasionally wait for another form or action to complete.

Comment: It happens randomly throughout the system. Sometimes after clicking on an object, the form will not appear in the foreground. A specific example is on the sales order details form, if you make a change to a line, you will get a pop-up warning. It almost always pops up in the background.

Comment: That does not happen for me, errors or warnings go to the Infolog window, which pops up to the foreground. Your case may be a special client environment. Specify what your operating environment is, OS version, AX version, local or remote client etc.

Comment: Windows XP SP3, AX 2009 SP1, local clients are being used (although I have seen the same result in the TS client as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to this question. It is related to a 3rd party addition that we have installed (IEM). I had to remove some code that they have that sets forms as modal (which ends up putting them in the background because of the base timeout function in AX because the code to make the form modal takes too long to execute). I had to make a change to Classes/SysSetupFormRun: Below is the code and where it was changed

```
    public void activate(boolean _active)
{
    ;
//    if (_active)
//        PUL_Modal::construct().hookModal(this);

    super(_active);
/* 
    if (_active)
        PUL_Modal::construct().checkModal(this);
*/

}
```

This returns the activate method to its previous state and prevents forms from going modal.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this from time to time, but I don't have any documented solution.

You could try to clear the users [AUC cache](http://www.google.com/search?q=ax+auc+cache&rls=com.microsoft%3ada&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1) and see if that helps.